# Subviews not appearing

Tags: swift

I'm learning swift and I have a problem displaying more than one subviews on the screen.
When I create two stack views, and add them to the view with `self.view.addSubview()`, only the last one created will be displayed.
I've read that "this method add a view on top of any other subviews", is the issue coming from that ?

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let hello = UILabel()
        hello.text = "Hello"
        hello.layer.borderWidth = 1
        hello.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        
        let world = UILabel()
        world.text = "world"
        world.layer.borderWidth = 1
        world.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        
        let testArray = [hello, world]
        
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.addArrangedSubview(hello)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(world)
        stack.frame = CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height: 50.0)
        self.view.addSubview(stack)
        
        let stack2 = UIStackView()
        for e in testArray {
            stack2.addArrangedSubview(e)
        }
        stackForIn.frame = CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 100.0, width: 100.0, height: 50.0)
        self.view.addSubview(stackForIn)
```

Don't pay attention to the way I create my stack, I'm just currently learning how to use UIStackView.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: When you run your app in Xcode, there's a menu option Debug->View Debugging->Capture View Hierarchy.  You can use that to see the size, location, and constraints of all your views.

Comment: Tank you, I've used this tip and now I can see that both of my stacks are present on the screen, but one is empty. I tried to use different objects to fill them instead of making both stacks identical, but it doesn't solve anything. Also, when I do `print(stack.arrangedSubviews)`, it appears that my Label are in the stack, but still not visible on screen. 
If you have any idea why, I'd be glad to hear it !

Comment: A view can only be a subview of one parent at a time, so putting them in #2 will remove them from #1.  I don't know why unique content doesn't fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need multiple copies of similar objects, I would suggest using functions to isolate their creation.  Other than that, I've tried to keep as close to your original code as possible.  (I have no idea what `stackForIn` is supposed to be.)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.addArrangedSubview(helloLabel())
        stack.addArrangedSubview(worldLabel())
        stack.frame = CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height: 50.0)
        self.view.addSubview(stack)
        
        let testArray = [helloLabel(), worldLabel()]
        let stack2 = UIStackView()
         for e in testArray {
             stack2.addArrangedSubview(e)
         }
         stack2.frame = CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 100.0, width: 100.0, height: 50.0)
         self.view.addSubview(stack2)
    }
    
    func helloLabel() -> UILabel {
        let hello = UILabel()
        hello.text = "Hello"
        hello.layer.borderWidth = 1
        hello.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        return hello
    }
    
    func worldLabel() -> UILabel {
        let world = UILabel()
        world.text = "world"
        world.layer.borderWidth = 1
        world.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        return world
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it seems to be working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension to see subviews of an UIView object in an array

```
extension UIView {
var allSubviews: [UIView] {
return self.subviews.reduce([UIView]()) { $0 + [$1] + $1.allSubviews }
    }
 }
```

Hope this help you :) happy coding

Comment: thank you for your help, however my knowledge in swift is too low at the moment to understand how to use this extension.. If you have any further explanation, it would be really nice :)

Comment: You are welcome :) Don't worry you will be learn step by step and these kinds of extensions makes your life easier. I suggest you to check out this links to figure out what behind the scene is:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheViewControllerHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH33-SW1
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1